# Specific Unicode character not displaying

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, unicode

I'm trying to span a simple [hexagon](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b22/index.htm) (⬢) in my page, this way:

`<span>&#x2b22;</span>`

but I'm receiving a rectangle with a cross in the middle, like an error icon. I tried with the decimal code (& # 1 1 0 4 2;), but I'm receiving the same error. If I try other Unicode character (₹), like:

`<span>&#8377;</span>`

it loads normally. What can be causing this symbol to be missing?

As far as I know this error is related to the page encoding. But if that were wrong, no other Unicode character would work, right?

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.2
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
```

Comment: What font are you using, not all fonts are full unicode aware. Try 'Arial'.

Comment: Using the Ionic's default font. Forced Arial font for span element, but the same error icon is show.

Comment: You have to find a font that supports the character; otherwise, you get the default replacement character `�` (which also can vary by font).  It displays fine above in StackOverflow, check this page source?

Comment: That was it! Looking in [FileFormat](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b22/index.htm) I could see the fonts that support U+2B22, from there I could choose the one that fits in my app. I thank you for your help!